# Forth order differential Equation (Beam on elastic foundation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The beam on elastic foundation is governed by $$y^{(4)}+4k^4 y=0$$

The following solution is very easy to derive
$$y=e^{(kx)}\left(C_1\sin(kx)+C_2\cos(kx)\right)
  +e^{(-kx)} \left(C_3\sin(kx)+C_4\cos(kx)\right)$$

However, the following one is also reported in some Russian literature (using Krylov functions)

$$y=C_1 \cosh(kx)\sin(kx) + C_2/2(\cosh(kx)\sin(kx)+\sinh(kx)\cos(kx)) + C_3/2\sinh(kx)\sin(kx) + C_4/4(\cosh(kx)\sin(kx)-\sinh(kx)\cos(kx))$$

Any reference to tie/help those two solutions together?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: $D^4+4k^4=(D^2+2k^2)^2-4k^2D^2=(D^2-2kD+2k^2)(D^2+2kD+2k^2)$, it should be obvious that the first variant does not fit.

Comment: I can't make head or tail of "the following one" since it has division signs and mismatched parentheses mingled together haphazardly. There are three division signs, and three open parentheses with only one closing parenthesis.

Comment: Yes, not the first solution is correct. Is there a reason given why the constant factors are not just combined with the "unknown" coefficients in the second solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Simplification of the first set of ode solution equations results in the second Krylov set by using identities and re-arranging the terms.

$$e^{kx}= \cosh kx + \sinh kx$$
$$e^{-kx}= \cosh kx - \sinh kx$$

Comment: In the equation in the question there are several  of what seem to be division signs $/$ which are not accounted for using this explanation. There are also a number of unclosed parentheses. I cannot understand the second solution, so I would be surprised if this is the correct answer to the question.

Comment: Corrected, apologies